# Activating multiple, unique popup windows with JQuery Dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, modal-dialog

I am a total beginner with Javascript and JQuery, and am trying to achieve the following:

In TinyMCE, I wish to be able to type the following:

- Click here to watch video 1
- [popup]path/to/file1.mp4
- Click here to watch video 2
- [popup]path/to/file2.mp4

JQuery would then use the [popup] hook to identify instances of where I want a dialog window, place an anchor to call that dialog, populate the dialog with a call to JWPlayer, and feed the path given in each instance to it. It is in the storing of each URL, and subsequently giving that exact URL to the player that I am having great difficulty.

Managed to get it going in the end - no doubt more elegant solutions exist. Thx to Ben below for bringing me along.

**UPDATED WITH WORKING SOLUTION**: The current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var num = 0;

//Find [popup] instances, increment the number
$("li:contains('[popup]')").each(function() {
    var nextnumber = num++;

    //add a general and a unique class to the list item containing the hook
    //this leaves only the path to file in that list item.
    $(this).addClass('popup' + ' ' + 'pop' + nextnumber);

    //Split on the hook, and save remainder of text (the path to file) as the 'path' attr
    var splitpath = $(this).text().split("[popup]");
    $(this).attr("path", splitpath[1]); 
    var path = $(this).attr("path");
    //alert($(this).attr("path"));

    //Get the previous list item (the call to action), and give it general and unique classes also.
    $thisArrow = $(this).parent().prev();
    $thisArrow.addClass('arrow' + ' ' + 'arr' + nextnumber);

    //Make the call to action an anchor link, with a general class identifier.
    $thisArrow.wrapInner('<a class="opener" title="Click to view video" path ="' + path + '"/>');

    //store path to poster as var, and hide the .popup li's
    $('li.popup').parent().hide();
});

$('.opener').click(function() {
    var Header = $(this).text();
    var popupURL = $(this).attr("path");
    var popupBG = "../contents/css/images/white-nontrans.jpg";

var thisDialog = $('<div></div>')

   //N.B. THE FOLLOWING HTML SHOULD BE ENTIRELY INCLUDED IN THE SINGLE .HTML() CALL
   //Otherwise Jquery will automatically close the <object> after the first line

   .html('<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="mediaplayer1" name="mediaplayer1" width="550" height="420">')
.append('<param name="movie" value="../mediaplayer/player.swf">')    
.append('<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">')
.append('<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">')
.append('<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF">')
.append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque">') 
.append('<param name="flashvars" value="file=' + popupURL + '&image=' + popupBG + '">') 
.append('<embed id="mediaplayer1" name="mediaplayer2" src="../mediaplayer/player.swf" width="550" height="420" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" wmode="opaque" flashvars="file=' + popupURL + '&image=' + popupBG + '" />')
.append('</object>')

.dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: Header, modal: true, width:570 });
thisDialog.dialog('open');
    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Pray forgive me if I'm missing something obvious here, but instances of what?  If you're talking about instances of things with the opener class, then the answer is to give them each an ID or a second class in addition to opener that you then grab using `$(this).attr()`, but I don't think that's what you mean.

Comment: Apologies - instances of the [popup] hook. For each hook, I want to embed a dialog, each then being filled with the unique data (the path to file) accompanying each hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relatively straightforward.  In the function that converts your [popup] hooks, define a `var counter = 0` prior to your `.each` loop.  Inside the loop, iterate the counter, and use that number to generate the unique data/markings, which you apply from within the loop.

This is a pretty brief description of the solution.  If you need more detail, just let me know.

edit: It seems like the problem would not be in the storage itself, but in identifying and getting control of the URL.  You should be able to store the url in an arbitrarily named attribute in the anchor tag.  It will be a technically "illegal" tag, so it won't do anything, but it will be there, it won't interfere with anything, and you'll be able to pull it out easily with the jquery `.attr()` function.

Getting the URL itself so that you can put it into your attribute of choice is probably best done using javascript's `split()`.  First, split on "[popup]".  This will give you an array where the first element begins at the beginning of the text block, and each subsequent element begins immediately after a "[popup]".  Then split each of those (other than the first) on ' '.  This will give you an array of that element, split by spaces - meaning that the first element in the array (as you've described it to me) should be the URL you're looking for.

edit2:

```
$("li:contains('[popup]')").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    //by my understanding of split(), the [0] element in the array would be the
    //bit before the "[popup]" string, so we want the [1] element. 
    var splittext = text.split("[popup]")[1];
    var splitsplittext = splittext.split[" "];
    //by my understanding of the way you've presented the use rules, the [0]
    //element of splitsplittext ought to contain your path now.  If you want
    //to make it more robust (say, allowing the user to put an optional space
    //between the "[popup]" and the path) then the logic here gets more
    //complicated.
    $(this).attr("pathHolder", splitsplittext[0]); 
}
```

Once you've done that, any time you have the `<li>`, you can call `$liNode.attr("pathholder")` to get back the address string

edit3: a few thoughts...
- You're setting multiple classes by adding in spaces manually.  My understanding of good coding practice suggests that you should just call addClass multiple times.
- You're doing a lot of things with selectors that you should be doing with variables.  For example, you use `$('li.pop'+nextnumber)` when you could just continue to use `$(this)`.  You add a class to an arrow just so you can use `$('li.arr'+nextnumber)` when you could just say something like `$thisArrow = $(this).prev()` and then used `$thisArrow` when you needed to refer to the thing.
- when you're defining the dialog, you don't need to use `var $dialog =` - you only ever need `var` or the `$`.  `var` means it's a javascript variable, which means it's strongly scoped.  The `$` means it's a JQuery object, which means that it's essentially scoped to the page.  Unfortunately, neither would work well for you here, as your code is written. The  javascript version would destroy itself almost immediately, as you cane to the end of the function, and the JQuery version would overwrite itself on the next cycle of the each loop.  In order to preserve it properly, you're going to have to actually write it in somewhere.  Also, I'm pretty sure that JQuery is going to look at `$('<div></div>')` and just get confused.  It looks like it's trying to be a selector and failing.

Comment: Thanks Ben for pointing me in the right direction. I have moved forward somewhat, but not knowing the language is making things very slow. I have updated my question and code to reflect where I am now with it - any help is welcome!

Comment: Answer updated.  I *think* this is answering the question I think you're asking.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, but it's escaping me - can you give me even an outline of the resultant code? I'd be grateful :)

Comment: Sure.  I'll put one together a bit later today.  In the meantime, though, I'd lie to check and assumption - each `<li>` tag has only one instance of "[popup]",  and the link is to apply to the entire `<li>`, correct?

Comment: Yup, and thanks. So does this mean there is no longer a need for incremented class names, etc? Can I simply apply each individual <li>'s attr as they are processed?

Comment: You could certainly do that.  You could also store the addresses in the class rather than in some arbitrary attr.  If you're not using the class for anything else it's good practice (and lets you set and access it a bit easier).  I just had it be an arbitrary attr because I thought you were/might be using the class in some other way as well, and you can get interference.

Comment: I think I shall keep the unique classes, as I could possibly use them again in my CSS. I didnt realise you could actually store it as an element class! I have updated the code above again to show its current state. Should I not be using the 'popupURL' variable in the code that includes the JWPlayer? I tried using `$(this).attr("pathHolder", splitsplittext[0]);` directly but that didnt work. If I can get that bit to work, I think it should be fine.

Comment: First answer is to make sure that your variables are holding what you think they are.  Output the contents of splittext and splitsplittext somewhere obvious on the page, and mess aroudn with it until you're sure you fully understand the behavior of the split() function.  I *think* I gave you the correct indices, but I don't guarantee it (and this is the sort of thing where minor changes in input text can have a fairly significant impact regardless).  Other than that, i'll take a look.

Comment: I've looked at the .split function, and am using the following: 
`var splitpath = $(this).text().split("[popup]");` folowed by `$(this).attr("path", splitpath[1]);`. This is the correct key for the path value I need, and outputting the `attr("path")` displays the path fine. When I use `$(this).attr("path")` in place of the popupURL variable I have in the code above however (in the flashvars statement), things fall down. How should I express it correctly?

Comment: Looking closer at the popupURL stuff, you're not doing enough to handle your quotation marks.  It looks like you're tryign to define a file inside a param name/value inside a jquery append call.  That actually requires three layers - a `'`, a `"`, and either a `\'` or `\"`, depending, to give you the quote inside the quote.  I suspect that that may be part of what's holding you up.  Also, take a look at the most recent edit to my answer.

Comment: Ouch :)  Thanks for all those pointers - really valuable to me in the long term too. I have updated the code in my original post to reflect its current state. I THINK it should be okay as per escaping quotation marks - it would be for PHP anyway, but Javascript is entirely new. What do you think?

Comment: you don't have to use \ on double quotes from inside of single quotes.  Instead, you use something like `'outer quote " middle quote \' inner quote \' middle quote end " outer quote end'`.  That way, when it unpacks, it's `"middle quote ' inner quote' middle quote end "`.  Also, you're still overwriting your `$dialog` variable every time you run through the each loop, and `$('<div />')` still doesn't work as a selector.  Read up on http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ a bit so that you understand them better.  Also, I'm done.  You need to spend some time reading documentation and testing.